# mistakes in Headers in fetch request

Tags: reactjs, http-headers, fetch, request-headers

I have a fetch request that works in browsers exept IE 11. It gets them from cache. To solve this problem I want to add headers in request.

```
async getResource(details) {
    const mainUrl = "http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity";
        const myHeaders = new Headers();
            myHeaders.set("Pragma", "no-cache");
            myHeaders.set("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
       
    
        const res = await fetch(`${mainUrl}${details}`, {
          mode: "no-cors",
          headers: myHeaders, 
     });
}
```

I add details according details that user choose(sum of money, number of paricipants) It may look like `'?participants=2&minprice=0.1'`
And send request

```
const details = await this.getResource(`?participants=2&minprice=0.1`);
```

And got a mistake

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Could not fetch ?participants=2&minprice=0.1, received 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve problem with IE by adding cache: "no-cache", and deleting headers.